# Trying to perform AJAX with jQuery doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX with jquery… this is what I'm trying to do :

```
    <div class="form">
            <form name="contact" class="js-form-contact" action="contact.php" method="post">
                <div class="clearfix">
                    <label>Mail</label>
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" size="44" name="mail"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearfix">
                        <label>Message</label>
                        <div class="input">
                            <textarea rows="6" name="message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- recaptcha -->

                    <br/>

                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="Enviar"/>
                    </div>

                    <div id="quote">
                        <p> :D </p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </form>
        </div>          
    </div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("btn primary").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "contact.php",
                data: $('.js-form-contact').serialize(),
                success: function(data) {                                               
                    $('.js-form-contact .btn primary').attr("disabled", true);
                    $('#quote').html("Rock!!");
                    // $('.column:first-child .box').after('<p class="msg">' + data + '</p>');  
                }
            });         
        });
    });
</script>
```

the contact.php is just doing "echo "Hello";" for now. When I click the submit button, the browser goes to contact.php and it echoes "Hello"...

What's the problem here? , I'm quite new with JS and jQuery so please bare with my noobishness :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery selector is wrong. It should be `$(".btn.primary")`. The `.` denotes that it's a class of the element you're looking for. No whitespace between classes means the element should have all those classes to match.

Furthermore, you should probably use [`event.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to prevent the click-event bubbling up to the organic submit handler.

To put the money where my mouth is...

```
// Note the parameter in the click-handler declaration
$(".btn.primary").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    // Do ajax magic here
});
```

Comment: if you need only AJAX behaviour then you just change button type from `submit` to `button`, this prevent submition with from form. In other way user can click submit button before JS initialized.